# PHP "if()" construct: can conditionals nest?

Tags: php, if-statement

Is it possible to do something like this in a php `if` statement:

```
if($a == '1' || ($b == '2' && $c == '3')) echo "foo walks into a bar";
```

(also, is the title of my question phrased correctly?)

Comment: Have you tried executing it with the appropriate values of `$a`, `$b` and `$c`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as `$a == '1' || ($b == '2' && $c == '3')` evaluates into a Boolean expression. Think of `||` and `&&` as mathematical operators, and you can apply brackets to them to alter their order of operations.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 2):

Yes

[php.net/if](http://php.net/if)

Answer (score 0):

Think you might need to bracket up the first condition:

```
if(($a == '1') || ($b == '2' && $c == '3')) echo "foo walks into a bar";
```

Comment: Brackets not needed, as `||` has a lower precedence than `==`

Comment: There's no need for that, `$a == '1'` is a Boolean expression by itself.

Comment: @rfw: Well, they are not *needed*. It's good practice though - if you rely on your knowledge of operator precedence, it *will* come back and bite you (Real Story(tm): "Of course I know the precedence, I don't need to check the manual- wait, what?" Turned out I remembered them wrong.).

Comment: @rfw: One word: __readability__. Although the computers don't care, I can vitually guarantee that {the person who will be maintaining the code after {the guy who was maintaining it after {the previous maintainer}}} will have strong feelings about it.

Comment: @Piskvor: Personally, I think adding conditionals on their own lines instead of bracketing them tends to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

They absolutely can! I think it'd be called something like a "multiple condition if()" statement.